# How to filter out a row using PANDAS?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I'm currently putting together a report for a university I work with that contains a field entitled 'Award Status Description' that contains information about the status of a scholarship - mainly if it has been Awarded. However, if a student is considered for a scholarship but not awarded one, their info and the scholarship appears in the report, but the description is empty. I need some way to filter out students that have a scholarship but no award status, however, I've never used PANDAS before and have no idea where to start.

Comment: `df = df[df['Award Status Description'] != 'pending']`. Don't forget to replace 'pending' with the correct value for those whose scolarships are pending

Comment: please consider using `where()` method on your pandas datafrme.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not particularly clear but maybe you need something like the following:

```
print(df)
  Award Status Description
0                  Awarded
1              Not Pending
2              Not Awarded
3                  Pending
4              Not Awarded
5              Not Awarded
6                  Awarded
```

To create a new `dataframe` with only the rows that equal to `Awarded`, you can use:

```
awarded_df = df[df['Award Status Description'] == "Awarded"]
```

that prints:

```
print(awarded_df)
  Award Status Description
0                  Awarded
6                  Awarded
```

To filter out those who are `Awarded` you can use

`not_awarded_df = df[~df['Award Status Description'].str.contains("Awarded")]`

which `prints`:

```
  Award Status Description
1              Not Pending
3                  Pending
```

Play with these commands and you will probably get what you want.